# Deploying sentence transformer ML Model with Flask Gunicorn, Load model never finish

Tags: machine-learning, flask, gunicorn, sentence-transformers

I Load sentence transformer model with flask Gunicorn, but the model never finish to load the model, anybody know why pls?

[image]

here is gunicorn log
[image]

Log flask without gunicorn
[image]

Comment: did you find any solution.. I am facing similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to load a sentence transformer model with :

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w 1 'app:create_app()' --timeout 1000000000
```