# abstract summarization using transformers model not working with Gunicorn server

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, gunicorn, huggingface-transformers

I am working on Abstract Summarization and choose Google-Pegasus-xsum model for it. It is working find on my local setup with Flask server. But when I tried it to serve it on gunicorn server, it never loads the model and goes into infinite loading and server never starts.

Here is my code:

```
from transformers import PegasusTokenizer, TFPegasusForConditionalGeneration
def load_model():
    print("Loading Model")
    model = TFPegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('google/pegasus-xsum')
    tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained('google/pegasus-xsum')
```

on starting the server, it calls the load_model but the model never loads, it print loading model, and then again after sometime server restarts and never goes after loading model.

Can anyone suggest what is the issue?

Comment: Can you describe the full error and about the servers? There's nothing wrong in the snippet given

Comment: The fact is there is nothing about it in the logs.. the log prints loading model and then nothing happen and it again restarts and restart

Comment: @kkgarg here is the similar issue, you can have a look at his log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768136/deploying-sentence-transformer-ml-model-with-flask-gunicorn-load-model-never-fi

Comment: Is it running inside a docker container? I assume gunicorn doesn't have write permissions?

Comment: @cronoik No it is not inside docket.. I run it through supervisor and also run it standalone but it keeps reloading.